# Show segue behave as a Modal presentation

Tags: ios, segue, xcode8

I have a Main screen and when I press a button I will be sent to the second view controller I create a storyboard segue of type: 'Show' but when I press the button the second screen is presented as a modal.
Ps: I'm already embed navigation controller in the first view controller
Ps2: the second view controller is placed in another storyboard file, so the connection of the segue is from the main view controller to a reference storyboard.

Comment: do both storyboards start with a navigationcontroller? are you sure that you are not trying to push a navigationcontroller itself onto another navigationcontroller's viewcontroller stack?

Comment: Thank you! I disable in the destination